# Copy Document library records to other library

Tags: sharepoint-online

In office 365 I have 2 libraries with few columns same columns names in both libraries.

So right now I want to delete first library.
I want to copy first document library documents with data to another library.

How to achieve this. I want in CSOM model.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can save as template to library and use it at destination.
2. If both libraries are in same site collection then you can use 'Content and Structure' for moving records.
3. you can copy the files from one document library using the Open with Explorer command under the Library tab in Library Tools, but it won’t copy the meta data. Also you need to golibrary and do copy and paste.
4. If both libraries are in different site collections and you dont want to write CSOM code just for one library then you can use 3rd party application like ShareGate trial version for 15 days. It will move everything smoothly.
5. Want to write your own CSOM code then

   For moving folders and files follow this [blog](http://jenkinsblogs.com/2016/07/27/clone-or-copy-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-from-one-site-to-another-using-csom/)